# Fetching data from database every five seconds to Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I am developing a Google maps application, latitudes and longitudes are coming from external device and storing into the database for every five seconds.

So I have to query the database every five seconds and get the new latitude and longitude of the database and moving the marker according to that.

How it can be done? Is it good to write ajax call?

Comment: which language do you want this done sir? whens the deadline? is there any other requirement??

Comment: @MechSoftware he wants us to give the entire soln i guess..

Comment: i wanted to query the DB for every five seconds, how it can be done?
is it good to write ajax call?

Comment: i hv posted an answer.. hope it guides you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that pulls data every few seconds and replots the markers: http://www.robotwoods.com/dev/so_septa.html

here's the PHP it's calling:

```
<?php
$route=(isset($_REQUEST['route']))?$_REQUEST['route']:23;
echo file_get_contents("http://www3.septa.org/transitview/bus_route_data/".$route);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will guide you in the right way. I guess I could do that atleast:

a) You could have a function that queries your server at intervals using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (check out a library like jquery) and in the callback function of the function process the response.

b) your server will send a response to the server Ideally it will be a json response of the form

```
{
 id:<>,
 lat:
 lng:
}
```

c) walk through [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) to see how you can remove markers etc. you can probably maintain hash of markers in an associative array like markers[key] where key will be the identifier of a marker, if and when the marker updates you can use this associative array to remove the marker as:

```
markers[id].setMap(null);
```

Code to add markers in callback:

```
var options = {
            position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);,
            icon: image,
            zIndex: zIndex,

        };
options.map=map;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options); //construct marker
markers[key] = marker;   //store the marker in array
```